# Twilio MMS wont send video. I keep getting error Error - 11200

Tags: twilio

I am linking this file for my media URL: [image: https://meetlete.com/media/small-met.mp4]

my goal is for this to be sent as a MMS. I first had a file size error. I fixed that, now I am stuck with this error.

The video will play on my browser. But not on my phone, but it will play on my laptop.

Does anyone have any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

> HTTP retrieval failure: Attempt to retrieve media failed. Possible
> Causes Web server returned a 4xx or 5xx HTTP response to Twilio
> Misconfigured Web Server Network disruptions between Twilio and your
> web server No Content-Type header attached to response Content-Type
> doesn't match actual content, e.g. an MP3 file that is being served
> with Content-Type: audio/x-wav, instead of Content-Type: audio/mpeg
>
> Possible Solutions Double check that your TwiML URL does not return a
> 4xx or 5xx error Make certain that the URL does not perform a 302
> redirect to an invalid URL Confirm the URL requested is not protected
> by HTTP Auth Make sure your web server allows HTTP POST requests to
> static resources (if the URL refers to .xml or .html files) Verify
> your web server is up and responsive Check to see that the URL host is
> not a private or local IP address Verify the ping times and packet
> loss between your web server and [www.twilio.com](http://www.twilio.com)
>
> Error Description There was a failure attempting to retrieve the
> contents of this URL. An 11200 error is an indicator of a connection
> failure between Twilio and your service. When Twilio requests a page
> from your server, we wait a maximum of 15 seconds for a response. A
> connection failure will occur if no response is returned in that time.
> There are many reasons a connection timeout can occur; common causes
> are long running database queries or outside processes and calls to
> external systems taking a long time to return. It may be possible your
> application experienced one of these issues. If you are encountering
> this error only intermittently, it is possible that your web server
> was temporarily unavailable or experiencing a network outage. 502 Bad
> Gateway errors If your debugger is reporting a 502 Bad Gateway error,
> this may mean that Twilio's internal server had trouble retrieving
> content from your website. Your request must contain a Content-Type
> that is valid. Twilio may also have had problems resolving your DNS
> name to an IP address, or issues with the network connection. Check
> that your web server is started, and is available over the public
> Internet.
>
> Request Inspector
>
> ```
> + Expand All
> GET https://meetlete.com/media/small-met.mp4 2021-02-21 05:05:07 UTC404 Request URL Parameters Message TextShow Raw
> Msg   "Attempt to retrieve media failed."
> httpResponse  "404"
> EmailNotification "false"
> url   "https://meetlete.com/media/small-met.mp4"
> LogLevel  "ERROR"
> ```

Comment: Have you checked any of the possible solutions offered on the [public docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/11200#possible-solutions)? Notice that error 11200 is related to an HTTP retrieval error, with a myriad of possible causes including networking issues between the webserver hosting the video and twilio.com, wrong configuration of headers (make sure that Content-Type header is set and in your particular case it's set to `Content-Type: video/mp4`) or wrong configuration of the server itself.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It might be the case that Twilio cached a 404 response to your video at some point.  I just tried sending a media message using your URL and it was processed correctly and the video was ingested by Twilio.

I would advise you try again. If you still find that your account has cached the URL response, you could try moving the video to a different address and trying with that instead.